# How to distribute the information from an Import table to the model tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I need to create a database normalizing some data I imported from a a csv file. The import table (Table `ImportA` from now on) contains all the data from the model, such as: `apartment_url`, `apartment_name`, `monthly_price`, `weekly_price`, `street`, `country`, etc.

In this model, according to the imported data, the tables I want to create are: table `Apartment` (will store `apartment_url` and `apartment_name`), table `Price` (will store `monthly_price` and `weekly_price` and table `Place` (`street`, `country`).

The 3 tables mentioned are created like this:

**Table Price**

```sql
create table Price (
    id serial,
    monthly money,
    weekly money,
    primary key (id)
);
```

**Table Place**

```sql
create table Place (
    id serial,
    street varchar(255),
    country varchar(255),
    primary key(id)
);
```

**Table Apartment**

```sql
create table Apartment (
    id serial,
    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    id_price int references Price (id),
    id_place int references Place (id),
    primary key(id)
);
```

Example of table `ImportA` data:

```
apartment_url    apartment_name    monthly_price    weekly_price     street    country
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    url1             name1              10               5             a          b
    url2             name2              10               5             c          d
    url3             name3              10               5             a          b
    url4             name4              7                3             x          y
```

In order to normalize this into the different tables, I inserted the data correctly to table `Place` and table `Price` like this:

```
insert into Place (street, country)
select distinct street, country
from ImportA;

insert into Price (monthly, weekly)
select distinct monthly_price, weekly_price
from ImportA;
```

So...

`select * from Place`:

```
id    street     country
--------------------------

1        a          b
2        c          d
3        x          y
```

`select * from Price`:

```
id    monthly     weekly
--------------------------

1        10          5
2        7           3
```

Issue is that in order to fill table `Apartment` I don't know how to relate `id_price` and `id_place` fields according to the tables created previously.

Following the example of `ImportA` data and the previous tables, the output I want if I executed `select * from Apartment` would be this:

```
    url     name     id_price     id_place
---------------------------------------------------
    url1    name1      1             1
    url2    name2      1             2
    url3    name3      1             1
    url4    name4      2             3
```

So... how can I insert the data to table `Apartment` properly using tables `ImportA`, `Place` and `Price`?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `join`:

```
select i.url, i.name, p.id, pl.id
from importA i left join
     price p
     on i.monthly = p.monthly and i.weekly = p.weekly left join
     place pl
     on i.street = p.street and i.country = p.country;
```

You can then insert this into your `apartment` table.

That said, it seems strange to split the prices into a separate table.  I think of those as measurable attributes on the apartment.  But you might have some reason fro splitting them off.  Also, the countries should probably be in a separate table as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped. Also the model is more complicated that I showed in here that's why in this example it can be weird to see. But in the real model table `country` exists and table `price` is necessary

Comment: Hi again @Gordon Linoff. Table `ImportA` in my model has `22985` rows (22985 different apartments). When I execute the query you provided, the number of rows returned is `1201`. I expected to get `22985` as every apartment should have a `monthly_price` and `weekly_price` on table `Price`. Also I expected there would be multiple price id repeated, but there are any. Do you have any clue on what's wrong?

Comment: @user157629 . . . That would suggest that you are either missing values in one of the reference tables, or that some of the values are `null`.  If the latter, you can use null-safe comparisons (`is not distinct from`), although that can affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is the `key` in table `ImportA`? if you want a normalized model you have to establish a `key` in the `denormalized` table because it's the only way to do a related model later on, if not how do you relate apartement with the other tables? You will have to export the keys from the `ImportA` to table `price` and table `place`.

The most probable fields to promote for being a  `key` on `ImportA` table  with the sample you are showing here
would be `(apartment_url, apartment_name)`, though there are many questions in the air, but there isn't a fact that
`(apartment_url, apartment_name)` is not going to repeat along the table, we want a normalized model in third normal shape at least
and we will have to give a `sequential id` to the `apartment` table.

We could do as follow:

First we create `price` table with its `key`, we'll have to export this `key` to `apartments` table as a `foreing key` later on

```sql
CREATE TABLE price AS SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY monthly_price, weekly_price) AS id,monthly_price, weekly_price 
                      FROM ImportA 
                      GROUP BY monthly_price, weekly_price;
```

expected output

```sql
SELECT * FROM price;
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+--+
| price.id  | price.monthly_price  | price.weekly_price  |
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+--+
| 1         | 7                    | 3                   |
| 2         | 10                   | 5                   |
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+--+
```

Second we create `place` table with its `key`, we'll have to export this key to `apartmentes` table as a `foreing key` later on

```sql
CREATE TABLE place AS SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY street, country) AS id, street, country
                      FROM ImportA
                      GROUP BY street, country;
```

expected output

```sql
SELECT * FROM place;
+-----------+---------------+----------------+--+
| place.id  | place.street  | place.country  |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+--+
| 1         | a             | b              |
| 2         | c             | d              |
| 3         | x             | y              |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+--+
```

Now we are ready to export the keys from `price` and `place` tables to `apartment` table

```sql
CREATE TABLE apartment AS
WITH ap AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY apartment_url) AS id,
       a.apartment_url AS au,a.apartment_name AS an, a.monthly_price AS mp, 
       a.weekly_price AS wp,street,country, p.id AS id_price
FROM ImportA AS a
JOIN price AS p ON(a.monthly_price = p.monthly_price AND a.weekly_price = p.weekly_price))
SELECT ap.id AS id,au AS apartment_url, an AS apartment_name,mp as monthly_price, wp AS weekly_price, p.street, p.country,id_price, p.id AS id_place
FROM ap
JOIN place AS p ON(ap.street = p.street AND ap.country = p.country);
```

expected output

```sql
SELECT * FROM apartment;
+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| apartment.id  | apartment.apartment_url  | apartment.apartment_name  | apartment.monthly_price  | apartment.weekly_price  | apartment.street  | apartment.country  | apartment.id_price  | apartment.id_place  |
+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 1             | url1                     | name1                     | 10                       | 5                       | a                 | b                  | 2                   | 1                   |
| 2             | url2                     | name2                     | 10                       | 5                       | c                 | d                  | 2                   | 2                   |
| 3             | url3                     | name3                     | 10                       | 5                       | a                 | b                  | 2                   | 1                   |
| 4             | url4                     | name4                     | 7                        | 3                       | x                 | y                  | 1                   | 3                   |
+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
```

I hope , it gives you some insights, regards.